# PunNub - Best way to recover lost messages when device was turned off?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, pubnub

We have multiple mobile clients (ios and android) subscribed to a channel-msg.

7 messages are being published to channel-msg by the server:
[image]

1. Messages 1-3 were published to channel.
2. The device got messages 1-3 via native PubNub.
3. The user turned the device off.
4. Messages 4-5 were published to channel.
5. The user turned the device on, and app in foreground.
6. Message 6 is published.
7. Message 6 arrives to the device.

At this point (in the "got PubNub message" callback in the device's code), I don't want to perform Message 6, because **I must perform Messages 4-5 first**.

I can use the history() API to get the lost messages, but with this strategy I am forced to perform the "history check" on each message I receive on the device, before I can execute it.

I there a better pattern/design to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub History

You don't need to call history for each individual message, rather, you retrieve all missed messages (up to 100 per `history` call).

Just save the timetoken of the last received message in a way that you can retrieve it when the app is relaunched (`NSUserDefaults`). When your app is launched, just use the timetoken as the `end` param (nil for `start` param) in your `history` call.

If you get 100 messages returned (the max) then it is likely you have more and you need to [call history again (paging through storage) and again until you receive > 100 messages](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/storage-and-history#paging).

Once you have received the last of the messages, [use the timetoken of that last message (the one closest to *now*), use that timetoken to `subscribe`](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/api-reference#subscribe_arg_2) to get any message between the last `history` call and your `subscribe` and continue to subscribe for further messages.